# How many trailing zeroes does 1000! have in base 8

Tags: elementary-number-theory

First I checked this for powers of two:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{9}\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{2^i}\right\rfloor=994$$

I was told the answer to this is $331$ since $994=331\cdot 3+1$.  I'm wondering why its $331$.

Comment: The solution effectively arises by finding out how many times,8 occured in the solution.

Comment: I saw a similar question..I cannot find now.

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Comment: I'm just not sure why the answer is 331 and now 994.

Comment: $1000!$ has $994$ factors $2$. You need three factors $2$ to get one factor $8$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate a bit on Daniel Fischer's comment, one has to take the number of times that a 2 factor would appear in 1000! which can be broken down as follows:

2 : 500

4 : 250   (Total: 750)

8 : 125   (Total: 875)

16 : 62   (Total: 937)

32 : 31   (Total: 968)

64 : 15   (Total: 983)

128 : 7   (Total: 990)

256 : 3   (Total: 993)

512 : 1   (Total: 994)

Since $8 = 2^3$, you want to divide 994 by 3 and take the quotient which is 331.